# Docker pattern for containers with a long initial command

Tags: docker

I am looking to package up a lot of local and open source code into a docker container that will distribute out to host machines to build and run.  The intent of the final container is to be executed command line style and output the result ex. (`docker run cmdcontainer args`).  The issue I have is the source that is distributed needs to be targeted and compiled on the specific host it will be running on once and this takes hours to complete.  However once compiled the command runs very fast.

So I am wondering if there is a known docker pattern for this sort of workflow:

Distribute Docker Container with source files -> Run the container to generate a new container with compiled binaries -> Subsequent runs execute the compiled container

Because this is basically layering a new container on top of the old it seems like this should be possible but I am a docker novice.

Comment: Can multiple versions of your image be created in advance, targeting different environments, or is every single host running your container unique?

Comment: Assume every host is unique.  Think distributing out a container to a commodity computer farm.  So there will be a large possible combination of CPU/GPU/Device Drivers that need targeted.  Technically they could all be cross compiled but that would leave a naming / reference nightmare for a task that is very easy on the target host.

Answer (score 0):

For every host being unique, the best solution I can come up with involved using a volume for persistence. You would need the following workflow in your entrypoint:

1. Check the version of your compiled code in the volume
2. If the version is a mismatch, delete the volume contents
3. If the version is not set or a mismatch, run your compile
4. Write the new version number to that volume
5. Run your app from the compiled version in the volume

This does require that your image build embeds a version number, e.g. a git hash. You can do this with a build arg:

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_REV=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) ...
```

And then your Dockerfile would include something like:

```
ARG GIT_REV
ENV GIT_REV=${GIT_REV}
```

Note that any users running without a volume will still see every run perform the compile.

Comment: I like the idea as a way to get it working but leaving stuff outside of the container means that an incomplete version of the product is visible on the main OS.  Also, if the container needs updated there now needs to be a mechanism to ensure that old versions of files are not left hanging around on the host OS.  Not huge deals but brings back some of the management that docker is supposed to remove.

Comment: @RandomString can't really say docker was designed to remove this sort of management since it's designed to run the same code+dependencies in different hosts easily, and you want different code per host. Step 2 covers the cleanup, just an rm inside your container on the contents of the volume.